# Random stopping in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm working on a multi-player game with a UDP server and I don't understand why my server thread stops by itself after the first iteration of its loop. Here is the code of the Activity which launches the thread:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

public ServerUDP t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    t = new ServerUDP();
    t.setRunning(true);
    t.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    t.setRunning(false);
    t.interrupt();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    t.setRunning(false);
    t.interrupt();

}
}
```

And here is the Server code :

```
 public class ServerUDP extends Thread 
 {
    private boolean mRun;

    private DatagramSocket serverSocket ;
    private byte[] receiveData;
    private byte[] sendData;
    private int ServerPort = 9000;

    ServerUDP()
    {
        try {
            if(serverSocket == null)
            {
                serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ServerPort));
                receiveData = new byte[1024];
                sendData = new byte[1024];
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (mRun) 
        {
            Log.v("socket","in loop");
            sendData = "test".getBytes();
            InetAddress local;
            try {
                local = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
                Log.v("socket","Sent"+sendData);
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,local, 8088);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            try {
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String receiveString = new String( receivePacket.getData());
            Log.v("RECEIVED",receiveString); 
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean b) 
    {
        mRun = b;
    }
```

}

The problem is that I only get one "in loop" message. My thread seems to die after one loop. I checked in debug mode and it's still alive, but it doesn't go through the server loop again.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that your thread is blocking in either the `send()` or the `receive()` call waiting for a response from your server.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably getting an exception other than `IOException` (an unchecked exception derived from `RuntimeException`). Try wrapping everything in your `run` method in a `try`...`catch(Exception e)` block.